# Get Model from record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can get model from collection:

```
User.limit(2).klass.name
#or 
User.limit(2).model.name
=> "User"
```

but how can I get model from a record?

```
item = User
item.klass
=> error.
```

Comment: `item.class.name` should do

Comment: @Emu  - yep that works.  thanks.

Comment: Added it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item.class.name` Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Use `model_name`

```
User.model_name.name => "User"

# You can access model's name by using `:to_s` or `:name`
User.to_s => "User" 
User.name => "User"
```